# Adding a external library to maven project with system scope

Tags: maven

I have added a external library to my maven project, using the system scope. The code compiles good without any issue. When i run the code using java -jar xyz.jar, i can see that it is not able to find the classes for the the external library which was added using the system scope. Following is the snippet added to pom.xml:

```
<groupId>abc</groupId>
        <artifactId>myartifact</artifactId>
        <version>v1-1.22.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
   <systemPath>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/lib/my.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Install the lib in a repository manager and use it from there...SNAPSHOT does not make sense for a system scop dependency.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the external jar to the classpath for it to be located by JVM. You can try this:

```
java -cp ".:/path/to/xyz.jar:src/main/resources/lib/my.jar" path.to.main.class
```